# How to run grunt server in dist directory instead of app directory?

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, yeoman

After `grunt build`ing my AngularJS app to my `dist` directory, I would like to test it out with `grunt server`. Problem is that `grunt server` just serves up all the code in my `app/` directory. Additionally, keep in mind that I created my app with `yo angular`.

Here is the server task code in my **Gruntfile.js**

```
grunt.registerTask('server', [
    'clean:server',
    'coffee:dist',
    'compass:server',
    'livereload-start',
    'connect:livereload',
    'open',
    'watch'
  ]);
```

Is there a way to make `grunt server` only serve up the built code in my `dist/` directory?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Whether or not you could do it isn't important. *What is important is that you should not use grunt server for this.* The server task in grunt as you can see does many things that you don't need in a dist folder, as well as the fact that they will all be hard coded for your app folder.

If you just want to try out the result of the dist folder, what you should do is just cd into the dist directory and then start a simple HTTP server like the one that comes with python.

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer
```

That should start a small server for you to try the dist directory out.

Comment: Thats what I do. I also sometimes have the dist directory symlinked (or actually pointed at) an apache controlled directory so i can serve it up as a vhost locally thats close to my actual production server.

Another thing you could/should do related to this is run your dist folder through your testing to make sure the built files truly are the same (only minified) as the source files.

Comment: @DerekR Thanks for that tip. I will try that out. Thanks yes, it works :)

Comment: @Eddie Monge Jr How do I run my dist folder through my testing? Not sure what 'my testing' means. Curious to learn though.

Comment: Python3's command is more memorable: `python3 -m http.server`

Answer (score 116):

The very short answer is

```
grunt serve:dist
```

That works with my yeoman-generated `Gruntfile.js` which contains:

```
  grunt.registerTask('serve', function (target) {
    if (target === 'dist') {
      return grunt.task.run(['build', 'connect:dist:keepalive']);
    }

    grunt.task.run([
      'clean:server',
      'bower-install',
      'concurrent:server',
      'autoprefixer',
      'connect:livereload',
      'watch'
    ]);
  });
```

Answer (score 3):

Although other have not advised doing this, I believe this is what you are looking for.  I do something like this in my server.js file when using express.

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV == 'production') {
    app.use(express.static('/dist'));
}else{
    app.use(express.static('/app'));       
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: why would they advise against this.

Answer (score 3):

The `grunt serve:dist` answer is the correct one, but the process is quite annoying because you need to compile your whole project into production mode every time you call grunt serve:dist.

What I did is I modified the `Gruntfile.js` in the `serve` task, removing the `build` task from the parameter sent to `run`. You need to manually build first with `grunt` or `grunt build` and then call `grunt serve:dist` and manually open the URL.

Comment: Do you have an example of this? Thanks

Comment: search the 'serve' task, you'll se a conditional ```if (target === 'dist') {```, inside it should return ```return grunt.task.run(['connect:dist:keepalive']);```

Comment: Anyway to prevent it from launching a new browser ?